# Visual Studio - setting version number of .EXE console application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, console-application, versioning

i have a simple .EXE console application, written in C# via Visual Studio 2008. how do i specify the .EXE's version number? I'd like to manually update it when I make updates to the program. I do not want to use the "Publish Wizard" (which supports Publish Version properties) since it creates a setup.exe and is over-blown for our simple app (which we deploy via XCOPY).

thanks,
matt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the Properties node in the Solution Explorer. In particular, search for `AssemblyVersion` and `FileVersion` attributes.